# Really slow torque 4 performance when adding simple key to criteria

Tags: java, postgresql, torque

I have a really odd performance problem with torque. Look at the loop below. It takes 13 seconds to run as is.

But if I replace the line
                c.and(PicturePeer.ID,SimpleKey.keyFor(2072));

with

c.and(PicturePeer.ID,2072);

the same loop runs in 0.2 second. This make no sense, because it is exactly the same operation, which is getting the Picture with id=2072;

I even enabled full query logs on my PostgreSQL database, and the select query on the database does not change when I change which of the 2 c.add methods I use. So I don't understand why the second solution without the SimpleKey is 50 times faster then the first.

The reason I found out, is that
c.and(PicturePeer.ID,SimpleKey.keyFor(2072))
is the method used by retrieveByPK which kills my performance.

```
 con = Transaction.begin();
            long start=System.currentTimeMillis();

            for(int i=0;i!=1000;i++) {
                Criteria c=new Criteria();
                c=new Criteria();
                c.and(PicturePeer.ID,SimpleKey.keyFor(2072));
    //          c.and(PicturePeer.ID,2072);
                PicturePeer.doSelect(c,con);
            }
            long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
            long diff=end-start;
            System.out.println("Load diff=" + diff);

            con.rollback();
```

The Picture relation from schema.xml looks like this:

```
<table name="picture" idMethod="native">
    <column name="id" primaryKey="true" required="true" type="INTEGER"/>
    <column name="filename" required="true" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <column name="name" required="true" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <column name="description" required="true" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <column name="role" required="true" type="VARCHAR"/>
</table>
```

If I call setLimit(1) on the criteria, the slow methods which uses the SimpleKey gets as fast as the fast method, so it looks like postgresql is using doing a table scan which make no sense to me. Especially since the version with slow and fast versions without limit gives exactly the same query log.

Here is the full log from postgresql. (The select 2 thing is the validate connection thing).

```
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT 2
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT picture.id, picture.filename, picture.name, picture.description, picture.role FROM picture WHERE picture.id=$1
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '2072'
LOG:  execute S_1: ROLLBACK
```

And just to be sure:

explain analyze SELECT picture.id, picture.filename, picture.name, picture.description, picture.role FROM picture WHERE picture.id=2072

Gives me:

```
 Index Scan using picture_pkey on picture  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=46) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id = 2072)
 Planning time: 0.043 ms
 Execution time: 0.022 ms
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone cares, I found the problem.

Torque ends up with a SimpleKey.keyFor value with the type BigDecimal. This causes problems because Postgresql then ends up not using its index when doing a select. (A type cast issue I guess).